# can I write on file.txt in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

this is the code I wrote

```
echo "Positive count =" > file.txt | grep -o -i positive IMDB_Dataset.csv | wc -l >> file.txt
```

on ubuntu and the result in the file was

```
Positive count =
26188
```

can I write it in the same line to become like this

```
Positive count = 26188
```

Comment: Are you really using CMD on Ubuntu? You're probably actually using Bash. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: BTW, the pipe between `echo` and `grep` does nothing. Replace it with a newline.

Comment: Can also use `printf "Positive count = %d\n" "$(grep -Foi positive IMDB_Dataset.csv | wc -l)" >> file.txt` (I tend to avoid `echo` for anything but literal strings)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Positive count =" `grep -o -i positive IMDB_Dataset.csv | wc -l` > file.txt
```

Or

```
echo "Positive count =" "$(grep -o -i positive IMDB_Dataset.csv | wc -l)" > file.txt
```

Comment: Backticks are deprecated. Use the newer command substitution syntax instead: `$()`

Comment: Also, it's best practice to include the substituted part within the double quotes

Comment: @wjandrea - Don't spread the misinformation _Backticks are deprecated._ They are conforming to current standards.

Comment: @Armali Maybe they're not deprecated per se, but it's best to avoid them. The newer syntax is much more flexible anyway.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 has a good writeup about why `$()` is better. (And newer? It's decades old.)

Comment: @Armali I don't appreciate your tone, so normally I wouldn't reply, but you raise some interesting points. For backticks, see: [Have backticks in *sh shells been deprecated? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/117037). When I say "deprecated" I mean that they've been superseded and should now be avoided due to their limitations. When I say "best practice", I don't mean that it's required here, but that it's required in some similar situations, so it's best to just do it all the time. See [ShellCheck SC2046](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2046)